# Conflict between circuitikz and babel french

Tags: babel, circuitikz

When I add the reference to the french babel package my code can't compile. Here is a MWE. I have searched for a solution during hours but I failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%adding the row below also doesn't help
%\usetikzlibrary{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[americanvoltages, fulldiodes,siunitx, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\equals}{=}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, thick]
            \draw (0, 0) to [V, i_>={$i$},
                                l={$V$}, invert] (0, 4)
                         to [R, l={$R_1$}] (4, 4) node[right] {$A$}
                         to [R, l={$R_2$}] (4, 0)
                         to node[ground]{} (0,0); 
            \draw[fill=black] (4,4) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` does help, but you must naturally put the command after loading tikz/circuitikz.

Comment: Arrrrgh. I want to hide in mice hole (thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623825/conflict-between-circuitikz-and-babel-french#comment1557317_623825), you should put the `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after loading `circuitikz`. And (unrelated) you should not use OT1 fonts (the default) --- you should have got a warning about it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%adding the row below also doesn't help
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[americanvoltages, fulldiodes,siunitx, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\equals}{=}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} 

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, thick]
            \draw (0, 0) to [V, i_>={$i$},
                                l={$V$}, invert] (0, 4)
                         to [R, l={$R_1$}] (4, 4) node[right] {$A$}
                         to [R, l={$R_2$}] (4, 0)
                         to node[ground]{} (0,0); 
            \draw[fill=black] (4,4) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works ok here.

[image]

Notice though that the trick with `\newcommand{\equals}{=}` is not needed anymore, since `circuitikz` version 1.2.7.